# Rewrite files from another directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code by one of community members named anubhava:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!newplace/).*)$ /newplace/$1 [L,NC]
```

Problem - code above work if it is in public_html and directory from where files are taken are in the first line (public_html/newplace) Problem is if you want to put .htaccess file in lower level of directory example: first/second/newplace/ and if you put .htaccess in second directory it won't work... any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code from sub-directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!newplace/).*)$ newplace/$1 [L,NC]
```

OR else by using a dynamic `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(.*?/)(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^ - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!newplace/).*)$ %{ENV:BASE}newplace/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I was thinking you are not here. I was looking previus answer on our other conversation. You were right I should only remove /newplace/ into newplace/. You are the best. I mark your answer here as correct. I will have one more question about .htaccess I make another post when I write it here so you can follow the link.

Comment: I am glad it worked out. I responded to your comment on other question too. Whenever I am online I respond to each & every comment addressed towards me.

Comment: Sure I will try me best to address your new question whenever you're ready.

Comment: Here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676105/rewrite-all-files-from-newfolder-to-index-html