# Rewrite all files from newfolder to index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/newfolder/(.+) /index.html/$1 [L,NC]
```

I want all files from newfolder (located in public_html) to be rewrite to index.html which is in public_html, ofcourse. Any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove leading slash from your regex to match URI:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mozilla|navigator|chrome) [NC]
RewriteRule ^newfolder(/|$) /index.html [L,NC]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: It's not working and it should be. It says 404 error page not found which is not true I check it all exist. Do you know some other way to do this? No meter on code I put as start. Your code, some new solution only to work....

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file in `newfolder` directory also?

Comment: No, ther is no other .htaccess files below not above in higher level directory. I put it "clean". I don't know why is this so complicate... Do you have some other code that - some other idea I can try?

Comment: Is this your very first rule? Are you browsing it from crome? If yes to both questions then try adding `R` to make it `RewriteRule ^newfolder/(.*)$ /index.html/$1 [L,NC,R]` and retest.

Comment: Same mistake 404 error document handle. But in address line it change when press enter: mywebsite.com/newfolder/second.html after pressing enter in address line became  mywebsite.com/index.html/second.html    Like it try to open second.html from index.html as it is folder... Do you know why?

Comment: ok then rule is working fine. 404 is appearing because `/index.html/second.html` is not a valid URL. You can make it `/index.html` instead of `/index.html/$1` to remove captured part.

Comment: It is true , it works now. But there is on unexpected problem... I mark you here as correct and make another topic for question related to thsi. i put here link when i compose question. It is very imoprtant as you going to see...

Comment: Yes you can post the link of new question here in comments section.

Comment: Here is link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678969/rewrite-showing-only-text-without-pictures-and-external-javascript

Comment: Anubhava I hope you see this I put here link for new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280631/verifying-googlebot-in-htaccess-file

Comment: I put you here link for regex question in dreamweaver: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321708/dreamweaver-regex-find-and-replace-using-regular-expression-2

Comment: Sorry I don't know about dreamweaver