# Dreamweaver Regex Find and Replace Using Regular Expression.2

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Dreamweaver Regex Find and Replace Using Regular Expression. 
I want to replace all a-letters with k-letter and all other latters to stay on their place unchanged. 
I have this  below:

```
Find: <body>nebojsa-sarac-([\s\S]*?)a([\s\S]*?).html
Replace: <body>nebojsa-sarac- $1 k $2.html
```

The problem is it change only first letter a into k and rest stay unchange in the example below:

```
<body>nebojsa-sarac-axxxax-axxaaxxa.html
into:
<body>nebojsa-sarac-kxxxax-axxaaxxa.html
```

The rest of a letters stay unchanged-not turn into letter k 
Does someone know the solution for this?

It really works in Notepad++
Do you know how to stop this code example

```
nebojsa-sarac-[a-z.-]*?\Ka|\G(?<!^)[a-z.-]*?\Ka - UNTIL .ahtmal AND DON'T CHANGE IT
```

Comment: Your pattern is basically "eating" what it matched. You can't do this without a non-fixed lookbehind assertion or some pcre/perl cryptic regex. So I think you can't do this in dreamweaver. Here's a thing that would work in the newest Notepad++ `nebojsa-sarac-[a-z.-]*?\Ka|\G(?<!^)[a-z.-]*?\Ka`, replace with "k". [Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hL1tJ9). Also [`Dreamweaver is the IE of IDE's`](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=8223283#8223283).

Comment: I put above: It really works in Notepad++
Do you know how to stop this code example
nebojsa-sarac-[a-z.-]*?\Ka|\G(?<!^)[a-z.-]*?\Ka - UNTIL .ahtmal AND DON'T CHANGE IT